# Migrating from thread to threading

Tags: python, multithreading

In Python 2, I used the module `thread` to easily create new threads, doing:

```
thread.start_new_thread(function_name, (arguments_tuple,))
```

I know I can run the same code in Python 3, except that I have to replace the `import thread` statement with `import _thread`. But as explained in Python docs:

> This module provides **low-level primitives** for working with multiple
>   threads (also called light-weight processes or tasks) — multiple
>   threads of control sharing their global data space. For
>   synchronization, simple locks (also called mutexes or binary
>   semaphores) are provided. **The threading module provides an easier to
>   use and higher-level threading API built on top of this module**.

How do I migrate that piece of code to the new module syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new module is destinated to OOP, so a example with `threading` would be:

```
import time
from threading import Thread

def sleeper(i):
    print "thread %d sleeps for 5 seconds" % i
    time.sleep(5)
    print "thread %d woke up" % i

for i in range(10):
    t = Thread(target=sleeper, args=(i,))
    t.start()
```

Changing `import thread` to `from threading import Thread`, and `start_new_thread(func, (args,)` to `Thread(target=func, args=(args,).start()` does the trick.